# PHP - session_set_cookie_params(), lifetime doesn't work

Tags: php, session, cookies, parameters, lifetime

As first, *I know a lot questions are like mine,* but I really don't know what I'm doing wrong...

As you might've guessed, I've a PHP script involving sessions.
Everything works like a charm, except setting the lifetime of my session.

I want to keep the session active for two weeks, but instead my (Chrome) browser says it's set to xpire after the browsing session (and it does). My PHP script:

```
session_name('DSWLogin');
// Naming the session

session_set_cookie_params(2*7*24*60*60);
// Making the cookie live for 2 weeks

session_start();
// Starting the session
```

It really doesn't work.

Thanks in advance,

Isaiah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your code as

```
session_start();
setcookie(session_name('DSWLogin'),session_id(),time()+2*7*24*60*60);
```

Comment: Thank you, though it now should be `time()+2*7*24*60*60`! Dunno why my method didn't work...