# PHP - Session is set after browser restart, but PHP acts as isn't

Tags: php, session, cookies, browser, restart

I've seen various questions like mine, though none provide the correct answer.
I've a PHP script:

```
session_start();
setcookie(session_name('DSWLogin'),session_id(),time()+2*7*24*60*60, '/');

//This will only be set once (when the user logs in)
$_SESSION['test'] = 'Yup, I am working';

if (isset($_SESSION['test'])){
echo 'Session is set and ready!';
} else {
echo 'No session was set...';
}
```

and that all works fine **except** after a browser restart, my PHP script ignores the session.

When my browser hasn't restarted yet, it'll `echo 'Session is set and ready!';` just fine.
And when I look into my cookie tab, it indeed says a cookie, named `DSWLogin` has been set with a certain value.

When I restart my browser, my cookie tab still  says that a cookie, named `DSWLogin` has been set with the same value it had before the restart, so **it is still there!** 
But my PHP script apparently ignores is, and outputs `'No session was set...'`...

Thanks in advance,

Isaiah v. Hunen

Comment: the session ends when the user closes the browser...

Comment: You need to escape the ' in 'Yup, I\'m working' - or use double quotes

Comment: @Blaine, that's not entirely true.

Comment: @Farkie, yes you're right, I did now

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is not really the correct way to achieve this. Sessions have two parts, a cookie with a session id set by default to expire at the end of the session (usually browser close) and a server side storage mechanism that is cleaned up automatically after a certain period of time after the last request was received.

What you are trying to do is extend the session to two weeks. While you could change the cookie settings and increase the timeout to session garbage collection doing this is not very reliable.

Instead you want to look at using a one time key stored in a cookie which acts as an alternate login path. This cookie can recreate the session just like a normal login would. There are some details that need to be considered for this to remain secure, but it will do what you are attempting to achieve.

Comment: So, you're basically saying a should use a cookie that will recreate my session after a browser restart? Wouldn't the cookie have to store the user's password then?

Comment: No, it would store a one time use randomly generated key. That key would be stored in the database referencing the user. Once its used, the old key will be destroyed and a new key created.

Comment: I guess that would work, but eventually, it just turned up to be my browser, Google Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Just because you are setting your session_id in some cookie doesn't mean it is THE session cookie.  Most browsers will purge session cookies on browser close. This is what you are seeing. Look at the cookies in your browser that are set when your session is valid and compare this to the cookies that are still remaining after browser restart. You will notice your true session cookie has gone missing.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php):

> The session name is reset to the default value stored in session.name
>   at request startup time. Thus, you need to call session_name() for
>   every request (and **before session_start()** or session_register() are
>   called).

Also if you want to change lifetime of session cookie, use [session_set_cookie_params](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) instead of forcing your own cookie.

Also read about session garbage collection and [configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime), changing cookie lifetime might not be enough.

Comment: Yes, I tried to, but that didn't work out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301114/php-session-set-cookie-params-lifetime-doesnt-work